# База данных для сбора статистики, работающая с JS

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Привет. Хочу логировать обезличенные данные пользователей для сбора статистики. Без базы данных, я так понимаю, мне не обойтись. Ну и, в конце-концов, я не имею опыта работы с БД, поэтому хотелось бы начать познавать эту часть программирования. Что можете посоветовать? Крайне желательно, чтобы данные в базу данных можно было отправлять напрямую из JS-кода. NoSQL? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть в HTML5 Web SQL. Можно использовать Local Storage. Если использовать только IE, то можно через COM объекты обращаться MsSQL, да и наверное не только.

Comment: Вы, наверное, не поняли задачу. Я хочу просматривать действия пользователей в админке. А для этого они должны записываться в БД, а при входе в админку оттуда доставаться.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, вы хотите записывать действия пользователя в приложении в браузере, при этом, чтобы само приложение браузерное напрямую записывало данные в СУБД на сервере?

Comment: нет, не так. Например, пользователь выполнил какой-то поиск по сайту с запросом, например, `?query=пиво`. Поиск выполняется посредством ajax-запроса. Так вот, когда пользователь нажал на кнопку "Искать", я хочу при помощи JS взять поисковой запрос `пиво` и положить его в БД.

Comment: Понятно, в данном случае пишете на js небольшую систему логирования различных событий и действий, которые вам нужны, эта система будет формировать ajax запрос к вашему серверу, на котором уже будет обработчик срабатывать, который поместит ваши данные куда угодно. Естественное если используете сервер nodejs , то лучше хранить в MongoDB, если php, то MySQL либо просто в файлах массивами серилизоваными. А по поводу прямой записи в СУБД с клиента и речи идти не может.